# bank transfer Prestashop

Tags: error-handling, prestashop-1.6

I am using Prestashop 1.6, but for some days I have a problem on bank transfer payment. I've just tried to update the module and activate debug, but nothing interesting appeared.

When try to confirm order (with bank transfer payment method) I have this error:

> object(cMAOrder)#850 (9) { ["documentDate"]=> string(10) "2016-10-14" ["ourReference"]=> string(9) "OGWWAYOHE" ["paymentMethod"]=> string(2) "BB" ["callBeforeDelivery"]=> bool(false) ["express"]=> bool(false) ["note"]=> string(0) "" ["invoiceRequired"]=> bool(false) ["details"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(cMAOrderDetail)#271 (4) { ["item"]=> string(13) "2000017000329" ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["unitValue"]=> string(8) "9.747800" ["discount1"]=> string(4) "0.00" } [1]=> object(cMAOrderDetail)#339 (4) { ["item"]=> string(13) "2000012010279" ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["unitValue"]=> string(10) "100.003400" ["discount1"]=> string(4) "0.00" } } ["customer"]=> object(cMACustomer)#839 (19) { ["country"]=> string(5) "Italy" ["ISOCountryCode"]=> string(2) "IT" ["payment"]=> string(2) "BB" ["companyName"]=> string(12) "my" ["taxIDNumber"]=> string(0) "" ["fiscalCode"]=> string(0) "" ["address"]=> NULL ["ZIPCode"]=> string(5) "00166" ["city"]=> string(15) "Roma" ["county"]=> string(2) "RM" ["telephone"]=> string(10) "123456" ["mobilePrefix"]=> string(2) "39" ["mobileNumber"]=> string(10) "123546" ["email"]=> string(23) "f.carciofolo@key4web.it" ["workingTime"]=> string(2) "39" ["contactPerson"]=> string(10) "123456" ["custSuppKind"]=> string(7) "7733248" ["category"]=> string(2) "VC" ["branch"]=> object(cMACustomerBranch)#852 (10) { ["country"]=> string(5) "Italy" ["ISOCountryCode"]=> string(2) "IT" ["companyName"]=> string(12) "my" ["address"]=> string(18) "street " ["ZIPCode"]=> string(5) "20093" ["city"]=> string(15) "Roma" ["county"]=> string(2) "RM" ["mobilePrefix"]=> string(2) "39" ["mobileNumber"]=> string(10) "123456" ["email"]=> string(23) "my@my.it" } } }

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check to see if the following file exists on your shop.

override/classes/order/OrderPayment.php

If yes, rename it to _OrderPayment.php and see if the issue is solved or not.